# Compiling many external .cs files into .dll using CodeProvider

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a program that can take user-generated .cs files and compile them into a library for later use (really just to prevent re-compiling them the next time the program starts). When I try to compile them into a .dll, I get an error saying that the file is in use by another program.

Here's my implementation:

```
CompilerParameters params = new CompilerParameters();
params.GenerateExecutable = false;
params.GenerateInMemory = false;
params.OutputAssembly = "test.dll";
params.TreatWarningsAsErrors = true;

CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

DirectoryInfo di = DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach(FileInfo fi in files)
{
    CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(params, fi.FullName);
    if(cr.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach(CompilerError ce in cr.Errors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ce.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The first file compiles just fine. Every file after that, though, gives me this error:

```
CS0016: Cannot write to output file "temp.dll" -- The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Why is it giving me this error? Do I need to invoke the compiler a different way if I intend to add many classes to an assembly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think, you need to change params.OutputAssembly = "test.dll" param for every independent cs.

Answer (score -1):

The CodeProvider class can compile multiple files at once into an assembly.

Rather than pass a single filename info CompileAssemblyFromFile, give it an array. Like so:

```
string[] files = { "a.cs", "b.cs", "c.cs" };
sCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(sCompilerParams, files);
```